# How to iterate over each user in database django tempting language

Tags: django, django-models

When you sign up for the site I am in the process of building, you pick whether you want to be a 'user' or a 'worker' and enter your location. For the workers, I want to display all the people trying to use the service('user') in the same location as the worker. I have the following model:

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    ROLE = (
        ('USER', 'User'),  # (value to be set on model, human readable value)
        ('WORKER', 'Worker'),
    )

    role = models.CharField(max_length = 7, choices = ROLE, default = 'USER')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

I also have a form with matching fields and it works fine, everything saves correctly.

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):

    birth_date = forms.DateField(help_text='Required. Format: YYYY-MM-DD')
    location = forms.CharField()

    ROLE = (
        ('USER', 'User'),  # (value to be set on model, human readable value)
        ('WORKER', 'Worker'),
    )

    role = forms.ChoiceField(choices=ROLE, required = True)


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name','last_name', 'birth_date','location', 'password1', 'password2', )
```

I have a `home` view:

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'core/home.html', {'user': request.user})
```

And a home.html, where depending on whether the account is a user or a worker it will display different things:

```
{%  extends 'core/base.html' %}

{% block head %}
    <title> Home</title>
{% endblock %}
{% block body %}

    {% if user.profile.role == 'USER' %}
        <h1>User Account</h1>



    {% elif user.profile.role == 'WORKER' %}
        <h1>Worker Account</h1>
        {% for userprofile in user.profile %}
            {% if userprofile.role == "USER" and userprofile.location == (insert location logic here) %}
                <h1>{{ userprofile.username }}</h1>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}


    {% else %}
    <h1>Error</h1>
    {% endif %}



{% endblock %}
```

How can I display to the worker accounts a list of all `USER` accouunts who share the same `location`. I am not sure if what I have in home.html is correct at all, but it is how I thought I should approach the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do that in your view and then send it to your html:

```
def home(request):
    if request.user.profile.role == 'WORKER':
        workers_with_same_location = Profile.objects.filter(location=request.user.location, role='WORKER').exclude(id=request.user.id)
        return render(request, 'core/home.html', {'user': request.user, 'other_workers': workers_with_same_location})
    else:
        render(request, 'core/home.html', {'user': request.user})
```

Then, in your html:

```
{% if user.profile.role == 'USER' %}
    <h1>User Account</h1>

{% elif user.profile.role == 'WORKER' %}
    <h1>Worker Account</h1>
    {% for worker in other_workers %}
            <h1>{{ worker.user.username }}</h1>
    {% endfor %}

{% else %}
<h1>Error</h1>
{% endif %}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hello , Jahongir, I am trying to implement the above code but it is telling me "Profile" in "workers_with_same_location = Profile.objects.filter(location=request.user.location, role='WORKER').exclude(id=request.user.id)" is not defined

Comment: @JustinO'Brien you need to import `Profile` from `models.py`

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it!